# Get rid of the "Instruments wants permission to analyze" prompt, from command line, in Yosemite

Tags: macos, command-line, permission, instruments

In our jenkins build automation environment we have several OSX nodes, now all updated to Yosemite, where we run ios simulator tests.

The problem is that on any newly introduced node simulator tests cannot run without further ado since instruments keeps prompting
"Instruments wants permission to analyze other processes. Type your password to allow this."

I've tried all the hints I could find, e.g. at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476131/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-authorization-prompt-from-command-line-instances-of,
like

```
1) DevToolsSecurity --enable

2) security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport allow

3) security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport is-developer

4) Other settings like
```

`<key>allow-root</key>
 <true/> <!--instead of false>`

`<key>authenticate-user</key>
 <false/> <!--instead of true>`

`<key>class</key>
 <string>allow</string> <!--instead of user>`

```
5) sudo security authorize -u [username]
```

Also I've made certain the [username] is in _developer group.

`dsmemberutil checkmembership -U "[username]" -G "_developer"
 => user is a member of the group`

Combination of 1) and 2 seems to have done the trick earlier, in Mavericks.
Any hint of what command line will do the trick in Yosemite will be very much appreciated!